# openCV for Android - NOT opencv-android-sdk

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk

I want to use some native c++ code/library in my Android application. The c++ part is heavily based on openCV.

I am aware of opencv-android-sdk and have seen plenty of detailed tutorials on how to do it with Android Studio (like [this one](http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/)), but these all just use the opencv-android-sdk that only supports a limited subset of openCV functions (I am not talking about those that do not make sense on a mobile device, like gpu-related functionalities, but some other functions that simply do not exist in the opencv-android-sdk and I need them for the c++ code).

**Anyway, my question is**: can I somehow compile and use the "full set of modules" of openCV in my Android Studio project (using NDK, etc.)?

I saw also [this one](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk), and it claims that "[it] will build most of the OpenCV modules [for android]", but it is not clear to me how to use it...

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK! I guess I figured it out!
Basically one needs to follow [this tutorial](http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/), but just replace the path in Android.mk to point to the compiled full version of openCV, instead of openCV-Android-SDK (as well as some other small changes; for those I just copy here what I have in `Android.mk` and `Application.mk`).

Eventually, my `Android.mk` looks like this (`OPENCVROOT` need to be set properly):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCVROOT:= /path/to/opencv-2.4.10/platforms/build_android_arm
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := hello
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And `Application.mk` looks like this:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

Just a short note on compiling openCV with Android NDK:

For compiling full openCV using NDK, one can still use the method mentioned [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk); the description is based on NDK-r8e, but if needed, one can download NDK-r10d and use it instead. I had to turn-off cuda-related parts in openCV source, in order to successfully compile it with NDK (just adding `-D WITH_CUDA=OFF` to `opencv-2.4.10/platforms/scripts/cmake_android_arm.sh` , in the last line, after `cmake`, does the job!). In case you need to have the nonfree modules (like SURF and SIFT, do NOT clone it from github, just download it in a single zip from [here](http://opencv.org/downloads.html); I used version 2.4.10 by the way).

Now I have access to almost all openCV functions in the native c++ code that I am integrating into my Android App!

I hope this helps others, too!

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate JNI (The Java Native Interface) which is a means of wrapping C libraries with Java.

Also you may want to consider getting hold of this book: [Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](http://www.amazon.com.au/Mastering-OpenCV-Practical-Computer-Projects-ebook/dp/B00AHCJNDG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1431481844&sr=8-1&keywords=mastering%20opencv)

Which goes into this in some detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually don't have any problems with integrating, compiling and running my c++ native code into an Android app as long as it is solely dependent on opencv-android-sdk; the problems arise when I want to use opencv with some extra modules and not the SDK. (the book by the way is great! Thanks; but it still lacks what I need)

Comment: This does not answer the question.