# How to use opencv for android which is built from trunk with extra modules

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

Thanks to tons of tutorials to build openCV from trunk, (specifically) I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202842/opencv-for-android-not-opencv-android-sdk), modified the android.mk as the following, and successfully build the OpenCV for Android with almost all extra modules.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java

MY_PREFIX := $(LOCAL_PATH)
MY_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(MY_PREFIX)/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_SOURCES:$(MY_PREFIX)%=%)

LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And then following the [official tutorial](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk), my cmake command:

```
cd opencv\platfroms\
mkdir build_android_arm
cd build_android_arm
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\android\android.toolchain.cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=\path\to\opencv_contrib-master\modules -DWITH_CUDA=OFF  ..\..
make
```

Now, I understand how to include the OpenCV library as an Android project and sample projects into eclipse to play with some existing OpenCV tools. But it's not clear to me, how can i use the extra modules easily. The library doesn't seems to have extra modules included. Some tutorials said build with NDK from scratch, but that would make no use of existing linked OpenCV library. I was wondering if there is a smarter way to integrate extra modules into current setup. Thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include it as an Android project; typically, you will use it as a *prebuilt* library in your project.

If you expect to access the additional module directly from Java, you will need to write your own JNI glue layer: don't expect **libopencv_java.so** to magically include the API for extra modules that you added to it.